# bio_endio and correct handling of the READ request

Tags: linux-device-driver

I'm need to process in the my own "bio_endio()" routine  data has been read from disk block device.
 Debug output show me :

```
[ 2366.375518] [ 0x0 DUDRIVER\__dua_show_bio:701] before [000] BIO 00000000f00b7491, src_iter sector/size/idx/done/bvec_done : 2056/0/1/4096/0
```

I expect that I can run over BVEC with follow loop:

```
for (vcnt = 0, src_iter = src->bi_iter; ; vcnt++)
    {
    if ( !src_iter.bi_size)
        {
        if ( !(src = src->bi_next) )
            break;

        src_iter = src->bi_iter;
        }

      src_bv = bio_iter_iovec(src, src_iter);


     /* there is decrypting stuff */

     }
```

But so loop is ended at "first iteration" and decryption stuff hav not be called.
So , do I'm need to save .bi_iter field before calling low level driver and restore it before loop? Or this tricks will not works because low level driver can splitting BVEC?

Answer (score 0):

READ request is comming with "finished" **.bi_iter** field. So, ether it need to use
bio_for_each_segment_all, or save and restore original **.bi_iter** field.